# Regular Expression to parse hostname from URL in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

Hey i'm curious as to how to parse out the host name in a URL using regular expressions in C#.

i have the following regex:

```
Regex regexUrl = new Regex("://(?<host>([a-z\\d][-a-z\\d]*[a-z\\d]\\.)*[a-z][-a-z\\d]+[a-z])");
```

but it throws an error when the URL does not contain a "http://", and it also does not parse out the "www." part of the url.

So how would i code a function that parses out the "hostname.com" from a URL, even if it does not contain a "http://". Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use regular expressions.

1. Convert 'http://' to '' (empty string) in your string - that basically removes http:// if it's there
2. [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28VS.71%29.aspx) the string on / as an array
3. The hostname is the element at index 0

Answer (score 3):

Why not do somethiing like this instead?

```
Uri uri;
if (!Uri.TryCreate(s, UriKind.Absolute, out uri)) {
    if (!Uri.TryCreate("http://" + s, UriKind.Absolute, out uri)) {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}

return uri.Host;
```

It's more lines but it's probably cleaner than a regex and easier to read.

Comment: This doesn't work when supply "testServer:666" . Host of URI will be Unknown. You should correct your sample like the following

Comment: if (!Uri.TryCreate(uriStr, UriKind.Absolute, out uri) || uri.HostNameType==UriHostNameType.Unknown)
 {
     if (!Uri.TryCreate("http://" + uriStr, UriKind.Absolute, out uri) || uri.HostNameType == UriHostNameType.Unknown)
     {
        throw new ArgumentException();
     }
}

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using a regex this should do: `^([a-z]+://)?(?<host>[a-z\d][a-z\d-]*(\.[a-z\d][a-z\d-]*)*)[/$]`

The trick is to have the last character match either a `/` or the terminator (`$`)

Answer (score -1):

`[^\/\.\s]+\.[^\/\.\s]+\/` - the only problem is that it requires `/` after hostname